# Does there exist any unrelativized separation between a quantum complexity class and a classical one?

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-computing, oracle-machines

I'm familiar with results of relativized separation for BPP-BQP, BQP-PH and NPC-BQP. I'm also aware that while e.g. Factoring is not believed to be in BPP, it hasn't been proven and so we're not quite near proving BQP!=BPP.

My question is, do we have any certain, theoretical, unrelativized proof that quantum computers are "superior" to classical one on any specific problem - Where here, I define superior to include any sort of runtime complexity superiority, so e.g. a quadratic improvement would qualify in this regard.

I'd expect Grover's algorithm to qualify for this criterion - But despite being supposedly "obvious", I'm not sure if it's been proven that classical computers can't solve it in sqrt(n) time as well, in a non-black-box model (i.e. unrelativized).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separations are known for constant-depth circuits. One recent result in this area is due to [Bravyi, Gosset, and Koenig](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00690) (see also the [journal version in *Science*](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.aar3106)). Recent independent works by [Bene Watts, Kothari, Schaeffer, and Tal](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=3313276.3316404), [Coudron, Stark and Vidick](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04233), and [Le Gall](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/frontdoor.php?source_opus=10843) strengthened the hardness result for classical circuits from worst-case hardness to average-case hardness.